# How to use multiple wildscards apache vhosts configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, virtualhost, apache-2.4

i know its possible to use wildcard on apache ServerAlias.
I'm trying to configure 3 sets but the configuration is falling back on one vhosts instead of each separate.

#### dev environment

```
ServerName dev.somedomain.com
ServerAlias dev.*.somedomain.com
docroot /var/www/dev.somedomain.com
```

#### release environment

```
ServerName release.somedomain.com
ServerAlias release.*.somedomain.com
docroot /var/www/release.somedomain.com
```

#### production environment

```
ServerName somedomain.com
ServerAlias www.somedomain.com *.somedomain.com www.*.somedomain.com
docroot /var/www/somedomain.com
```

But when i browse to dev.test.somedomain.com i get the contents of somedomain.com (not dev.somedomain.com).
What am i missing here ?

Comment: Make sure that the production VHosts get loaded last.

Comment: And if that is not possible (im using directadmin) ?

Comment: That is how Apache works, it uses the first VHost that matches the Wildcard. If production is first, it will always be matched. No other way as far as I can tell.

Comment: First of all, thanks, Is there a way to make a wildcard that matches abc.somedomain.com and not def.abc.somedomain,com e.g. a wildcard that only matches 1 dot (.) ?

Comment: Nope. Apache ServerName and ServerAlias do not support regex or other complex matching. Although I will post a solution for you in a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I also said in my comments, you can fix this by changing the order of the VirtualHosts in the Apache configuration. Since this is not possible, I will point you to 3 alternatives:

1. Use [mod_vhost_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html). This might also not be an option, but still.
2. Use separate IP addresses for Production/Development/Release. This should be relatively easy if you are on an internal network/behind a NAT.
3. Use separate ports in Apache for each VHost and put a HAProxy instance on the same server that redirects to the correct port. In HAProxy you can do regex matching on the Host header much better.

Comment: Although not i was hoping I came to the same solution.